# What is the closest font to the google logo that is freely available online?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to make a replica of the google homepage and I'm looking for a font style to make the logo. From what I can tell the official font is not publically available. I'm looking for a font that's freely available (somewhere like in Google Fonts or some other website) that I can link to my HTML and CSS files.

[image]

Comment: "official font is not publically available" - this is an image.

Comment: I'd say "Product Sans"

Comment: @ninadepina that is not made publically available. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_Sans which also describes how the font was adapted to form the logo, which as has been pointed out, is an image.

Comment: It's a geometric sans by typographic category. [Futura](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futura_(typeface)) and [Avenir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenir_(typeface)) belong in the category and would work well enough if you want similar aesthetics.